# Tesseract OCR and gImageReader didn't work

Tags: ocr, tesseract, image-recognition

I am C# .Net developer and a friend asked me to make a program that would translate pdf handwriting numbers to excel files.

Well, there is an example of the type of file he is translating by hand.

![[1]: http://s19.postimage.org/pt56qyfeb/example.jpg "example"][1]

I tried to use the gImageReader but using english words (since there wasn't numbers option), even if I turn the pdf to the correct position and select the place where there are only numbers, the output is totally wrong.

If somebody know a better way to achieve my goal, please let me know.

best regards